# Changing Opacity of colors in an image Java

Tags: java, swing

I've written a code that gets a specific RGB color from an image and stores that in a file.

Now I'm trying to change the opacity of each of the colors in the image. For example, decrease the red color gradually until it is not there, and each time the color has decreased, the change that happened will be saved in a file. How can that be done?

Here's the code that I've written to get a specific color

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.Buffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BMPtoArray {
public static void getBlue(BufferedImage image){}
public static void getGreen(BufferedImage image){}
public static void getRed(BufferedImage image){
    int blue = 0x000000FF;
    int green = 0x0000FF00;
    ColorModel cm = image.getColorModel();
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = 
image.copyData(image.getRaster().createCompatibleWritableRaster());
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
    for (int row = 0; row < newImage.getHeight(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < newImage.getWidth(); col++) {
            int color = newImage.getRGB(col, row);
            color &= ~green;
            color &= ~blue;
            newImage.setRGB(col, row, color);
        }
    }
    try {
        ImageIO.write(newImage, "bmp",new    File("C:\\Users\\Mhamd\\Desktop\\3rd year 
first semester\\Analysis and Coding\\labs\\2.2Java\\src\\newIMGRed"+".bmp") );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void getBlack(BufferedImage image){
    int red = 0x00FF0000;
    int blue = 0x000000FF;
    int green = 0x0000FF00;
    ColorModel cm = image.getColorModel();
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = 
image.copyData(image.getRaster().createCompatibleWritableRaster());
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, 
isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
    for(int count = 1; count<=8;count++) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(newImage, "bmp", new 
File("C:\\Users\\Mhamd\\Desktop\\3rd year first semester\\Analysis 
and Coding\\labs\\2.2Java\\src\\newIMGBlack" + count + ".bmp"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < newImage.getHeight(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < newImage.getWidth(); col++) {
                int color = newImage.getRGB(col, row);
                color &= ~blue * count / 8;
                color &= ~red * count / 8;
                color &= ~green * count / 8;
                newImage.setRGB(col, row, color);
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Mhamd\\Desktop\\3rd year 
first semester\\Analysis and Coding\\labs\\2.2Java\\src\\circleRGB.bmp"));
   getRed(image);
   getBlue(image);
   getGreen(image);
}
}
```

The `getBlue` and `getGreen` methods are the same as the `getRed`, just with different colors.

The picture below shows what I want to do. As you can see, the image starts with its colors, and gradually the red, green, and blue are decreasing until they are gone, and each time the color decreases, the change in the image is saved in a file.

[image: Picture]

Comment: “As you can see, the image…” No, I’m afraid I can’t see it.  task30, task31, task32, and task33 all look black to me.  Instead of taking a picture with a phone, use the PrintScreen or PrtScr key to take a screen shot, then use Paint (or any other editing tool) to reduce the image to only those file previews.  This will preserve every pixel exactly.

Comment: @VGR *"use the PrintScreen or PrtScr key"* Spot on. For just the focussed window, use Alt+PrtScr. This image (copied to the clipboard) can then be pasted directly into an answer (if it needs no trimming). I love that it frees me from saving the image to disk!

Comment: @VGR the pictures that I'm talking about are from task 37.bmp to task 30.bmp , I can't take a screenshot as this picture was sent to me from someone else , it's just showing how the colors are being reduced , task32 and 31 have a little bit of color and at task 30 the colors are gone , the are just gradually being reduced

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've edited the picture again , I can't take a screenshot as this picture was sent by someone  , just look at the pictures from task37.bmp to task30.bmp , it shows how the picture starts with Bright RGB and then gradually reduces until the RGB are completely gone , task30.bmp is where the colors are gone , task 31.bmp 32 and 33 have colors but are very opaque and can't be seen

Comment: Are you just trying to fade the image to black?  Or do you have to perform some operation separately on red, on green, and on blue?

Comment: @VGR operation seperately on red on green and on blue , like I need to control the opacity of the red green and blue until they disappear from the image.

Comment: So, you want a method that reduces the amount of red in an image, a method that reduces the amount of green in an image, and a method that reduces the amount of blue in an image?  Your screen shot seems to show them all being reduced at the same time.

Comment: @VGR exactly reduce red green and blue at the same time

Comment: Then you are in fact fading the image to black.  There is no reason to have separate methods for red, green, and blue.  I suggest keeping the original image, and multiplying each pixel’s red, green, and blue components by 7/8.  (For instance: `red * 7 / 8`)  The [Color](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html) class makes this easy if you don’t want to do the bitwise operations.  Then create another image, multiplying by 6/8, then again using 5/8, 4/8, 3/8, 2/8, and 1/8.

Comment: @VGR ok so I've done what you told me and it's doing the job , but I can't think of how to insert it to the for loop which loops through the width and the height of the image, I'm inserting another for loop and iterates 8 times starting from 1 until 8 so that it removes the colors gradually and after each loop it saves the image in the file , I've edited the question and pasted the method which removes the red green and blue but I can't think of a way to do that , could you please check the method above in the question

Comment: `~blue` is always the same value.  You will find it much easier to use the getRed, getGreen, and getBlue methods of the Color class.  Start with `new Color(newImage.getRGB(col, row), true)`.

Comment: @VGR the method that I wrote is called `getBlack()` int the code above , could you try and run the method and tell me what's wrong with it , I can't think of a way , I'm stuck

Comment: @VGR I don't know why it's not doing job , I mean what I'm trying to do is I've created a for loop which loops 8 times , and a counter COUNT is used so that I can divide it each time by 8

Comment: I'd likely just paint a very translucent (almost transparent) black wash over the entire image repeatedly. Is there a reason you don't do that?

Comment: Bitwise operations like `&=` are not the same as mathematical operations like `*` and `/`. You cannot combine them.  You will need `int redValue = color & ~red;` before you can do any math on the value.  And you need to use `image.getRGB`, instead of examining newImage each time.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I can't , I'm asked to specifically work with the red blue and green colors and not add anything extra

Comment: @VGR could you please check the `getBlack()` method I've written , and rewrite it ? beacuse it's not doing the job , and I can't figure out what's the problem

Comment: Isolate the red value using `int redValue = color & red;`.  Then, *in a second statement,* do `redValue = redValue * count / 8`.  **Do not** try to do this in a single statement.  Multiplying a bit mask by count / 8 is not correct logic and is not the same as multiplying a color value.

Comment: @VGR if you could provide me with the method I would really appreciate it

Comment: @VGR I don't need the entire assignment , I just need the method which is the `getBlack()` , I've been trying to do it but I just can't figure it out (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stepping through your method’s logic:

```
for(int count = 1; count<=8;count++) {
    try {
        ImageIO.write(newImage, "bmp", new File("C:\\Users\\Mhamd\\Desktop\\3rd year first semester\\Analysis and Coding\\labs\\2.2Java\\src\\newIMGBlack" + count + ".bmp"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Writing the image before you have made changes will not produce the intended result.  You need to write the image *after* you have modified the pixels.  Remove the Image.write call, and remove the try/catch.

```
    for (int row = 0; row < newImage.getHeight(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < newImage.getWidth(); col++) {
            int color = newImage.getRGB(col, row);
```

Do not read the pixel from `newImage`.  Read it from the *original* image:

```
            int color = image.getRGB(col, row);
```

Finally, these lines are incorrect:

```
            color &= ~blue * count / 8;
            color &= ~red * count / 8;
            color &= ~green * count / 8;
```

`~blue * count / 8` is performing math on the *bit mask* for *all* blue values in all pixels.  It is not performing math on the actual pixel value.

First, *isolate* the blue value:

```
int blueValue = color & blue;
```

Now you have a value on which you can perform math:

```
blueValue = blueValue * count / 8;
blueValue &= blue;
```

You can update the color by first clearing the existing blue value:

```
color &= ~blue;
```

…and then updating the color with the new blue value:

```
color |= blueValue;
```

And of course, you’ll want to do the same with the red and green values.

Finally, after both for-loops are complete and all pixels have been updated, *only then* should you write your file:

```
            newImage.setRGB(col, row, color);
        }
    }
}

try {
    ImageIO.write(newImage, "bmp", new File("C:\\Users\\Mhamd\\Desktop\\3rd year first semester\\Analysis and Coding\\labs\\2.2Java\\src\\newIMGBlack" + count + ".bmp"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```